# C# MonoGame Memory Management

Tags: c#, monogame

I come from a C/C++ background and am learning C# as I go along. I found this example online.

```
KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();​​​​​​​​

...​​​​

previousState = state;
```

At first glance, it didn't seem like the most prudent way to do it. I changed it to this:

```
Array.Clear(pressedKeys, 0, 103);

Array.Copy(Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys(), pressedKeys, Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys().Length);

...

Array.Clear(prevKeys, 0, 103);

Array.Copy(pressedKeys, prevKeys, pressedKeys.Length);
```

But then I looked at the original code again and now I'm confused. To me, it originally looked like my way was better because I thought I wasn't leaving allocated memory spaces behind, but it seems like Keyboard.GetState() creates a new state object instead of just returning the reference to its own member, as it has to be called every game loop (I tested this). So if this is the case, either way would leave behind one unreferenced keyboard state object for the garbage collector to clean up: previousState's object in the sample, and the one returned in the function call in the first Array.Copy() in mine. If that's what's going on, mine's slightly worse because it holds two extra arrays and performs extra operations on them. Is this necessarily the case? Or do I have no idea what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3):

KeyboardState is a struct. It's allocated on the stack and copied by value, so there is no GC involved unless you somehow box it onto the managed heap.

Write the code in the most natural way possible (the first way) and optimize your bottlenecks later when you have profiling data that actually shows there is a bottleneck.

Comment: This is good advice, but a reference type may contain a field that is a value type (`struct`) in which case it will also be heap allocated. An implementation is also free, or so I would assume, to allocate them on the the heap if it wants. It is more correct to say that `struct`s can be, and typically are, stack-allocated.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am not sure you are right that an implementation is free to allocate value types on the heap. The formal C# specification states the following in section 12.7.11.1:

"The new operator implies creation of an instance of a type, but does not necessarily imply allocation of
memory. In particular, instances of value types require no additional memory beyond the variables in
which they reside, and no allocations occur when new is used to create instances of value types."

In any event, in the real world the code shown in the first example would put the value on the stack.

Comment: That's talking about something a bit different, the meaning of the `new` operator. Regardless I agree that they will be stack allocated in practice unless they are boxed or constituents of a reference type.